How can I format header and footer using ODS Word in SAS?
I would like using ODS Word in SAS to set the header with companyname on the left and sectionname on the right as in the image.
proc template;
   define style styles.mystyle;
   parent = styles.word;
  class PageNo /
      marginbottom = 8pt
      verticalalign = bottom
      textalign = right;
 end;
run;
ods graphics on;
options nodate ;
ods word file="msword.docx" 
   style=mystyle;
proc freq data=sashelp.class compress ;
   tables age*sex/plots=freq;
run;
ods word close; 

Is it possible?
image

Header?? Do you mean a TITLE?  Or something above the title somehow?

ODS WORD will render the first encountered SAS TITLE in the document header.
TITLE will honor styling directives.
title j=l "Left text" j=r "Right text" j=c "Center text" ;

Many strategies employed in creating ODS RTF output will work in the experimental destination ODS WORD (which means there is no official documentation).
